# What is weighted entropy?

Tags: entropy

I got this question but I don't understand what 'weighted entropy' mean here ?
[image]

Age is the x-axis and Salary is the y-axis.

Compute the following:

- The entropy of the full set of points.
- The entropy of the set of points that belong to the left child (those with Salary < 75).
- The entropy of the set of points that belong to the right child (those with Salary ≥ 75).
- The **weighted entropy** of the two children.
- The decrease in entropy due to this split.